# MiniZinc: type error: no function or predicate with this signature found: `all_equal(array[int] of var opt int)'

Tags: minizinc

I'm not understanding this error, this code works:

```
include "all_different.mzn";
include "all_equal.mzn";

int: DIMENSION = 3;
int: MAX_DIGIT = DIMENSION * DIMENSION;
set of int: DIGIT_RANGE = 1..MAX_DIGIT;
set of int: POS_LINEAR_RANGE = 1..MAX_DIGIT*MAX_DIGIT;
array[DIGIT_RANGE, DIGIT_RANGE] of var DIGIT_RANGE: grid;

% constraint rows
constraint forall(i in DIGIT_RANGE) (
  all_equal([grid[i, j] | j in DIGIT_RANGE])
);
```

But this doesn't:

```
include "all_different.mzn";
include "all_equal.mzn";

int: DIMENSION = 3;
int: MAX_DIGIT = DIMENSION * DIMENSION;
set of int: DIGIT_RANGE = 1..MAX_DIGIT;
set of int: POS_RANGE = 1..MAX_DIGIT;
set of int: POS_LINEAR_RANGE = 1..MAX_DIGIT*MAX_DIGIT;
array[DIGIT_RANGE, DIGIT_RANGE] of var DIGIT_RANGE: grid;

% get x, y from a 1..81 position representation
function POS_RANGE: pos_x(int: n) = (n-1) div MAX_DIGIT + 1;
function POS_RANGE: pos_y(int: n) = (n-1) mod MAX_DIGIT + 1;

% foreach digit have a map of its positions on the grid
array[DIGIT_RANGE] of var set of POS_LINEAR_RANGE: positions;
% all positions in the set of positions for a digit corresponds to the
% same digit
constraint forall(i in DIGIT_RANGE) (
  %all_equal([grid[i, j] | j in DIGIT_RANGE])
  all_equal([grid[pos_x(pos), pos_y(pos)] | pos in positions[i]])
);
```

The error is "MiniZinc: type error: no function or predicate with this signature found: `all_equal(array[int] of var opt int)'". I understand what the error is saying, but i don't get why the array elements i use are "var opt ints" and not "var ints".

If i change the call to "all_equal" to "all_different" it works, which seems to say those functions has different parameter declarations, i don't understand why... But well, this is just an observation. My real question is: Why the array i'm passing to all_equal is an array of "var opt int" and not "var int"? How to rewrite my code to make this work?

Thanks!

**EDIT1**: Just for some background. What i'm trying to write is a program that gives me valid sudoku grids having the additional constraints that they have main diagonal symmetry, and that each time a digit maps to another by symmetry that map is constant over all the grid. I've got the following:

```
int: DIMENSION = 3;
int: MAX_DIGIT = DIMENSION * DIMENSION;
set of int: DIGIT_RANGE = 1..MAX_DIGIT;
set of int: POS_RANGE = 1..MAX_DIGIT;
set of int: POS_LINEAR_RANGE = 1..MAX_DIGIT*MAX_DIGIT;
array[DIGIT_RANGE, DIGIT_RANGE] of var DIGIT_RANGE: grid;

include "all_different.mzn";
include "all_equal.mzn";

% constraint rows
constraint forall(i in DIGIT_RANGE) (
  all_different([grid[i, j] | j in DIGIT_RANGE])
);

% constraint cols
constraint forall(j in DIGIT_RANGE) (
  all_different([grid[i, j] | i in DIGIT_RANGE])
);

% constraint blocks
array[DIGIT_RANGE] of DIGIT_RANGE: first_j = [3 * ((block_n-1) mod 3)+1 | block_n in DIGIT_RANGE ];
array[DIGIT_RANGE] of DIGIT_RANGE: first_i = [3 * ((block_n-1) div 3)+1 | block_n in DIGIT_RANGE ];
constraint forall(block_n in DIGIT_RANGE) (
  all_different(
    [grid[i, j] | i in first_i[block_n]..first_i[block_n]+2, j in first_j[block_n]..first_j[block_n]+2]
  )
);

% get x, y from a 1..81 position representation
function POS_RANGE: pos_x(POS_LINEAR_RANGE: n) = (n-1) div MAX_DIGIT + 1;
function POS_RANGE: pos_y(POS_LINEAR_RANGE: n) = (n-1) mod MAX_DIGIT + 1;

% foreach digit have a map of its positions on the grid
array[DIGIT_RANGE] of var set of POS_LINEAR_RANGE: positions;
% all positions in the set of positions for a digit corresponds to that
% digit
constraint forall (i in DIGIT_RANGE) (
  forall(pos in positions[i]) (
    grid[pos_x(pos), pos_y(pos)] = i
  )
);
% the positions of a digit are a complete set of that digit's positions
% (cardinal is 9)
constraint forall (i in DIGIT_RANGE) (
  card(positions[i]) = MAX_DIGIT
);
% actual restriction: for each position for a digit, symmetric position
% has to always be the same digit
constraint forall (i in DIGIT_RANGE) (
  all_equal([grid[pos_y(pos), pos_x(pos)] | pos in positions[i]])
);

solve satisfy;
```

The error i get is with the very last constraint, which is the one imposing the "constant mapping" restriction.

Answer (score 2):

If you use array comprehensions that use a decision in the iterator, then the amount of elements in the array isn't known during time of compilation/flattening. It instead has to be decided by the solver.

MiniZinc solves this by making some variables “optional”, and the decision whether the variable exists or not is decided when the problem is solved. This is described in more detail in the [Hidden Option Types](https://www.minizinc.org/doc-2.7.6/en/optiontypes.html#hidden-option-types) section of the MiniZinc tutorial.

Comment: Thanks! Got it... I completely rewrite the above because that wasn't the way to go (new to minizinc) so i don't have an issue anymore, but: what's the minizinc way of constraining the values in an array of var set with allequal / alldifferent? That was really the question, as i didn't understand optional vars maybe i didn't formulate it properly... If you know how i'm marking this as correct as soon as possible. I'm wondering if i should fully edit / reformulate my question...